# How to find (all) integer overflows in a C program?

Tags: c, debugging, overflow

I am working on a large project that generally works just fine, but shows serious issues once the input data size exceeds some limitations.

These issues are (suspected) only due to signed integer overflows like these:

```
int a, o;
// Initialize a and o
int x = (a+o) >> 1);
```

Obviously, once the sum of a and o overflows (gets larger than 2^31-1), x is no longer the mean of a and o.

Is there a generic way to find all of these integer overflows in a running program?

I am thinking of a tool like Valgrind or a GDB extension that breaks at every integer arithmetic instruction, takes the parameters and compares the correct result (calculated with a larger-sized datatype or arbitrary-precision arithmetic) with the actual result. If the results differ, it should output a warning, trigger a debug break or something like this.

I know, how to check a single arithmetic instruction for overflows (e.g. checking the sign for additions), however due to the vast amount of code, it is not viable solution for me to go through the whole project and insert checking code everywhere by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large code base, `Coverity` is a good tool. I am not sure it will detect `all` integer overflows or not, but its worth giving a try.

Answer (score 3):

You have to work through all the code and work out what the limit on the user-input is and validate the input. You may also need to re-write some algorithms to reduce overflow issues.

As the example you give doesn't work for negative values, you should be using an `unsigned int` anyway, giving you an extra order of magnitude already.

**Edit:**
gcc has the `-ftrapv` option, but this <s>usually doesn't actually do anything</s> only works with `-O0`. If you are taking the approach of trapping overflows when they happen, you still need good knowledge of the code in order to test it fully.

Comment: I roughly know, what the limit on the user input is. The problem with working through the code is, that the project has more than 200k lines (199k of them not written by me) and I fear that it would be pretty impossible to check them by hand for overflow-prone code.

Comment: @ChrisM - If you're in a position where you can't trust that code someone else wrote is correct then you probably shouldn't use it. Business practices should be in place to deal with things like this (reviews, testing, etc.). If it's just you with this code and no-one else around, you're going to need to spend some time reading through it all anyway.

Comment: Okay, it's a pity. I just hoped there was a way to find the problematic sections in the code (probably a dozen, or some more) automatically.

Comment: @ChrisM - You could set set conditional breakpoints in gcc for unexpected values, but that still requires knowing where all the variables that are involved in arithmetic are.

Comment: The *"usually doesn't actually do anything"* caveat for `-ftrapv` only applies when compiling with optimisation.  With `-O0`, it should work fine.

Comment: @caf: It doesn't work for me with -O0 still. I checked by comparing the binaries generated with and without -ftrapv, and found them to be completely identical.

Answer (score 0):

How about a script which goes through the code and replaces all "a+b" with DEBUGADD(a,b) - where you can do:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
int addFn(int a, int b) {
  long long m;
  int n;
  m = (long long)a + (long long)b;
  n = a + b;
  if (m != (long long)n)
    printf("PANIC!\n");
  return n;
}
#define DEBUGADD(a,b) addFn(a,b)
#else
#define DEBUGADD(a,b) ((a)+(b))
#endif
```

Comment: Just make sure your script handles whitespace, casts, order of operations, and return types correctly :)

Comment: Better would just be `assert(((a <= 0) || (b <= INT_MAX - a)) && ((a >= 0) || (b >= INT_MIN - a)))`, since a similar expression will work for `long` and `long long` as well.